Azure Alert Rules with AzureopenAI
we are using AzureDevops pipeline to create azure LAW alert rules using arm template and alert rules are enabled with payload.json which generates alert rule name, description and query with each alert rules which are triggered.
{ "AlertRuleName":"#alertrulename", "AlertType":"#alerttype", "Severity":"#severity", "Application":"#Application", "Text":"#alertrulename fired with #searchresultcount records. #description", "SearchQuery":"#searchquery" }

ARM file as below
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "actionGroupName": {
            "type": "string"
        },           
        "query": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "logAnalyticsWorkspaceId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "AlertRuleName": {
            "type": "string"
        },    
        "tags": {
            "type": "object"
        },
        "schedule": {
            "type": "object"
        },       
        "severity": {
            "type": "int"           
        },                          
        "operator": {
            "type": "string"         
        },  
        "threshold": {
            "type": "int"
        },
        "autoMitigate": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": false
        },
        "enabled": {
            "type": "string"
        },        
        "customWebhookPayload": {
            "type": "object"
        },             
        "location": {
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "type": "string"
        }    
},    
    "resources":[
        {
            "type":"Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules",
            "name": "[parameters('AlertRuleName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-04-16",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": "[parameters('tags')]",            
            "properties":{
                "displayName": "[parameters('AlertRuleName')]",
                "description": "[parameters('AlertRuleName')]",
                "enabled": "[parameters('enabled')]",
                "source": {
                    "query": "[parameters('query')]",
                    "dataSourceId": "[parameters('logAnalyticsWorkspaceId')]",
                    "queryType":"ResultCount"
                },
                "schedule":"[parameters('schedule')]",
                "action":{
                    "odata.type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.Microsoft.AppInsights.Nexus.DataContracts.Resources.ScheduledQueryRules.AlertingAction",
                    "severity": "[parameters('severity')]",
                    "aznsAction":{
                        "customWebhookPayload": "{ \"AlertRuleName\":\"#alertrulename\", \"AlertType\":\"#alerttype\", \"Severity\":\"#severity\", \"Application\":\"#{appname}#\", \"Text\":\"#alertrulename fired with #searchresultcount records. #{alertDescription}#\", \"SearchQuery\":\"#searchquery\" }",
                        "actionGroup": "[array(parameters('actionGroupName'))]"
                    },
                    "trigger":{
                        "thresholdOperator": "[parameters('operator')]",
                        "threshold": "[parameters('threshold')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

We have  ationgroups linked with these each alert rules and which is enabled with webhook(functio napp) to notify in teams channel and which are working fine as expected.
To enhance the above approach further on  the alert notification part, we are trying to integrate this alert rules with our private azureopen AI instance , so that the team can get much more insight about the alert reason and suggestion to fix the alert.
So in MS side is there any inbuilt solution to integrate the alert rrules \alerts with AzureOpenAI or  whether we can send the alerts payload directly to the AzureOpenAI instance  to get it achieved?

No there is not. An Azure function might be useful to receive the alert and process it using openai.

Can you share the ARM template here.

Added to question

It seems like there is no possible approach to integrate Azure Alert rules with open AI. @Vowneee

@PeterBons Is there any scenario, where we can integrate the payload json created from alert rules to OpenAI instance or, we have already teams channel integrated with alert rules with actiongroup webhook. Can we make use of any of the above to achieve what we are looking for?

I would suggest you use a custom API to configure the webhook in the action group to forward the alert payload to a custom API endpoint. Is it works for you? @Vowneee
